# What is the different uses of attrs in android?

Tags: java, android, layout, attr

First of all, i know that there plenty of post about the issue and i think i read them all. If someone ask i will attach them for approve :)

I have an issue with attrs. The issue is that sometimes i see programmers using it when they create a **custom view** but sometimes i see that they are used also when building a theme.
For example:

```
  <declare-styleable name="Main_Theme">
   
    <attr name="background" format="reference" />
    <attr name="backgroundCard" format="reference" />
    <attr name="secondaryTextColor" format="reference" />
    <attr name="primaryTextColor" format="reference" />
    <attr name="primaryColor" format="reference" />
    <attr name="secondaryColor1" format="reference" />
    <attr name="secondaryColor2" format="reference" />
    <attr name="secondaryColor3" format="reference" />
    <attr name="dividerColor" format="reference" />
```

and then they creates a theme using it.
For example:

```
    <item name="background">@color/dark_theme_background</item>
    <item name="backgroundCard">@color/dark_theme_card_background</item>
    <item name="secondaryTextColor">@color/dark_theme_scores_new</item>
    <item name="primaryTextColor">@color/dark_theme_primary_text_color</item>
    <item name="primaryColor">@color/dark_theme_primary_color</item>
    <item name="secondaryColor1">@color/dark_theme_secondary_1_color</item>
    <item name="secondaryColor2">@color/dark_theme_secondary_2_color</item>
    <item name="secondaryColor3">@color/dark_theme_secondary_3_color</item>
    <item name="dividerColor">@color/dark_theme_divider_color</item>
```

Then i saw them using those items as values for attributes in layout activity xml file
So i really can't understand the variety use of attrs.
I hope someone can help me to understand cause i feeling very confused

Answer (score 2):

attr is used when make custom view with custom attribute.
If you define attr, you can use it in xml file.

Normal View use default attribute such as width, height, background, text etc.
So you can use it in xml file.

```
<TextView
    android:width="match_parent"
    android:height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:text="@string/app_name" />
```

But there is no attribute for your custom view.

If your custom view needs dividerColor attribute, you can't use it android:dividerColor as following.

```
<YourCustomView
  android:width="match_parent"
  android:height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@color/white"
  android:dividerColor="@color/black" /> // it caused compile error.
```

So you need your attribute for use in xml file.
For it, you need declare attrs in attrs.xml file. (xml file name can change.)

```
<declare-styleable name="Main_Theme">
    <attr name="dividerColor" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

And then you can use new attribute in view xml file.

```
<YourCustomView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" // need define app
      android:width="match_parent"
      android:height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@color/white"
      app:dividerColor="@color/black" /> // it's works
```

**PS:** You need to additional code for use custom attr in YourCustomView class file.

```
TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.Main_Theme);
dividerColor = ta.getColor(R.styleable.MainTheme_divider_color, Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: First of all i think that in order that your last example will work the `Main_Theme` needs to be replaced with `YourCustomView`.. Secondly i can't understand how `<declare-styleable` can be used for custom view and also as a value for attributes in the xml layout

Comment: You need to some code in custom view class for get custom attribute. I wrote comment in my answer.

Comment: Styleable name can be anything. you can just use it in code in R.styleable."Styleable Name".

Comment: Can you refer to the block of code with item name= ?
In adition in your example.. the divide_color can be now an attribute of *TextView* for example?

Answer (score 1):

Attr represents an attribute in an element. Simply put attrs are allowable quantities that are defined in a schema associated with a document.

Whenever we create a custom view we don't want the view to accept every possible value under the sky, so we define a few values that can be accepted by the view using the attr interface. these attributes are defined using declare-stylable that enables you to define attributes for custom views.for example:

```
<resources>
   <declare-styleable name="PieChart">
       <attr name="showText" format="boolean" />
       <attr name="labelPosition" format="enum">
           <enum name="left" value="0"/>
           <enum name="right" value="1"/>
       </attr>
   </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

this custom view accepts showText and label attributes. the showText accepts a boolean value and the labelPosition accepts values: left and right. like the example below

```
<PieChart
    showText="false"
    labelPosition="left"/>
```

---

similarly in themes we need to define certain attributes that can be used inside the theme for example if we create 2 themes and want to define a different primary color that will be used by the app when using either theme. we first declare the color attr like so in the attrs.xml:

```
<declare-styleable name="Main_Theme">
    <attr name="color_primary" format="color" />
  </declare-stylable>
```

and then inside the styles.xml we define the values for the color_primary attr for the 2 themes

```
<style name="theme_one">
    <item name="color_primary">#ff0000</item> // red
</style>

<style name="theme_two">
    <item name="color_primary">#00ff00</item> // green
</style>
```

this value could then be used in layout files like so: `?attr/color_primary`

---

similarly attr could be used to define a wide range of things. an attr element itself has 2 attributes the name with which you refer it in other parts of the code and the format which could be `color`, `boolean`, `dimension`, `float` etc. for example enums could be defined as:

```
<attr name="some_enum_attr">
  <enum name="value_one" value="1" />
  <enum name="value_two" value="2" />
</attr>
```

Comment: What "prevents" color_primary to be an attribute of a View in layout xml (exactly as it with PieChart)?   Does `<attr name="showText" format="boolean" />        <attr name="labelPosition" format="enum">` can be used as attribute of any View inside layout xml?

Comment: it's not about prevention as much as what the view recognises as legal and illegal values. you cannot use showText and labelPosition as attributes of views that haven't declared these attributes in their schema like shown in the answer, please forgive me if I didn't understand your question properly

Comment: Every thing ok. I appreciate your help.. But i really want to understnad so please don't get mad on me... You say: `you cannot use showText and labelPosition as attributes of views that haven't declared these attributes in their schema like shown in the answer`. **But** what is the "relationship" between `PieChart` and `CustomView`, so `CustomView` can use those attributes but other views cant? what you did for it? and why `color_primary` can't be an attribute inside `CustomView`? What is the difference between `CustomView`and ``Main_Theme`?

Comment: What makes the attribute `showText` to be recognize that isn't exist for 'color_primary'? and why  `showText` is recognized in `CustomView` but not in TextView

Comment: Well firstly sorry for a small mistake I actually meant the name of the custom view is PieChart and forgot to change it in the XML example above. Now, coming back to you're question, all views declare a schema in which it declares the attributes that it accepts. It then uses this schema to read the values that are provided by the user while defining this view in the layout.xml file. So in the layout.xml file if you give it any custom attribute (that is not present in it's schema that was defined by the developer when the view was created) it won't be able to understand/read it!

Comment: you might understand it better from the docs on creating a custom view: https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view

Comment: similarly if color_primary is defined in the same schema (in which showText and labelPosition is defined) that is being used by the view it could use color_primary as an attribute as well along with showText and labelPosition!

Comment: Theoretically beside being part of the the custom  view, does `showText` can be declared inside `<style name = "Main_Theme">` as follows:
`<item name = "showText"> false /<item>`?